# Unit Test Using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am unit-testing an `async` method that returns a `List<T>`.  This method has a dependency on a mapping class/interface.  In my unit-test, I am mocking the mapping class using `moq`.  The test runs okay, and the returned list has items, but the values of the items is null.  I think the problem is because I haven't stubbed-out the mapping classes methods properly.  I don't have a lot of experience with testing, so any guidance is appreciated.

Test Method:

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("CSR.Data.Tests.Services.ServiceSearchTest")]
public void SearchAccount()
    {
        // Arrange                 
        var mapper = new Mock<CSR.Data.Mapping.Interfaces.IMapper<Account, AccountDTO>>();

        mapper.Setup(i => i.Initialize());
        mapper.Setup(i => i.ToDomain(It.IsAny<AccountSearchResult>())).Returns(It.IsAny<Account>);
        mapper.Setup(i => i.DomainToDto(It.IsAny<Account>())).Returns(It.IsAny<AccountDTO>);

        var service = new ServiceSearch(null,mapper.Object);         
        string accountNumber = "123";
        string accountName = "";

        // Act 
        var results = service.SearchAccount(accountNumber, accountName);            

       // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(results.Result.Count >= 1);
        }
```

Method/Class That I'm Testing:

```
    public class ServiceSearch : IServiceSearch
    {
    public ServiceSearch(IMapper<Claim, ClaimDTO> claimMapper, IMapper<Account, AccountDTO> accountMapper)
            {
                _claimMapper = claimMapper;
                _accountMapper = accountMapper;
            }

    public async Task<List<AccountDTO>> SearchAccount(string accountNumber, string accountName)
            {
                var accounts = new List<Account>();
                var accountDTOs = new List<AccountDTO>();
                var results = await Task.Run(() => base.AccountSearch(accountNumber, accountName).Result);

                if (results != null && results.Count > 0)
                {
                    //Map DH to Domain
                    _accountMapper.Initialize();

                    foreach (AccountSearchResult result in results)
                    {
                        accounts.Add(_accountMapper.ToDomain(result));
                    }

                    //Map Domain to DTO
                    foreach (Account account in accounts)
                    {
                        accountDTOs.Add(_accountMapper.DomainToDto(account));
                    }
                }
                return accountDTOs;
            }
}
```

Comment: You should avoid using `Result` (and probably also `Task.Run`) in your `async` code.

Comment: @StephenCleary...Don't I want the value of the Task? What's wrong with Task.Run here? I'll create another questions if you think it's worthwhile.

Comment: `await` is the proper mechanism to retrieve the result. `Task.Run` should only be used to call CPU-bound methods from a UI layer, which does not appear to be the case in this code.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the best place to use a Mock object because you are going to spend a lot of time writing your test objects and mock results.  The issue with the setup call is that you haven't configured anything to send back in the result.  A correct example would be:

```
// you would fully configure this object
AccountDTO expectedResult = new AccountDTO();  

mapper.Setup(i => i.ToDomain(It.IsAny<AccountSearchResult>())).Returns(expectedResult);
```

Now you can use the setup to configure different accountDTOs for different inputs.

You call also configure a callback to generate the account at test time:

```
mapper.Setup(i => i.ToDomain(It.IsAny<AccountSearchResult>())).Returns<AccountSearchResult>(sr => {
   // build and return your dto here 
});
```

However,  unless your mapper is expensive to run or create, I think you'd better off just ensure that it is fully tested and acceptable and then use it to go ahead and generate the DTOs directly instead of trying to mock it out.

Comment: I removed the mock and used an instance of IMapper and it works fine.  I can do this, but I don't understand why the mock doesn't work.  Aren't mocks the right way to do this to avoid tight coupling, etc.?  I also changed the returns as you suggested and get back the classes with null property values.  Would I need to manually populate these classes to get them working?

Comment: The line between when to mock and and when to use an existing implementation is a fuzzy one for me.  I've spent a lot of time trying to keep tests up to date when I've over mocked a system.  With something like a data mapping, you still have a 'loose coupling' in that you aren't dependent on the implementation of the mapper class, but you are dependent on the structure of the input and output.  If all you are doing is copying properties between instances of the different types, then that's really all your mock would be doing.

Comment: @BigDaddy yes, you need to manually populate the classes.  (Or use an existing implementation.)   If you want true isolation you need to manually populate for sure.

Comment: @MattClark is correct, if you are going to use Moq you are manually populating the expected values.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually setup an object in the ".Returns" call.  You need to make sure to setup the ".Returns" to actually have an object with values.

Comment: Please see my response to Steve Mitcham.